# Как правильно написать название жеста?

Tags: орфография, заимствования, названия

Как верно?

1. Жест Намасте.
2. Жест намасте.
3. Жест "намасте".
4. Жест "Намасте".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет причин выделять кавычками или наделять слово прописной, как это делается в словарных статьях.

*Namaste-поклон; поклон namaste; namaste-приветствие; namaste-прощание.
Приветствовал гостя традиционным намасте; приветствовал гостя поклоном намасте.*

Существуют две версии слова — намасте и намастэ. Лучше, на мой взгляд, в отношении читабельности дело обстоит со второй формой, — *Э* сразу сигнализирует о нерусской природе слова.